# Duplicate initialization both in subclass & supreclass

Tags: java, initialization

Lately, I came across this example:

**Abstract Car class**

```
    public abstract class Car {

    private final Product product;
    private final String carType;

    public Car(Product product,String carType){
        this.product = product;
        this.carType = carType;
    }
}
```

**BigWheel Class which extends Car class**

```
    public class BigWheel extends Car {

    private final Product product;
    private final String carType;

    public BigWheel(Product product, String carType) {
        super (product, carType);
        this.product = product;
        this.carType = carType;
    }
}
```

My question is simple - why would one want to initialize `product` & `carType` variables twich in both classes? why initializing them in the `super` isn't enough?

Comment: Each variable is initialized once. Initializing the super class members doesn't initialize the sub-class members and vice versa. The real question you should be asking is why both super-class and sub-class have properties with the same name and type. This seems redundant.

Comment: As your product and carType variables are private in the parent class it can not be visible to the child class.

Comment: so, If the super class members were defined as `protected` - we could remove the sub class members and just use the `super`, right?

Comment: Use `protected` modifier and declare them once, then you can use `super` in child class.

Comment: If I was reviewing this code, I'd mark it as plain wrong. But you do not need neccessarily change the access modifier of the fields if there are protected (or public) accessor methods.

Comment: @Fildor - well, it feels wrong to me too.

Comment: Is there a `pulic Product getProduct()` in Parent class ?

Comment: Next error. There probably should be one except it is only used internally. Hit "blame" on your code management system and slap the user that wrote this with a large trout!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have been sufficient to make the fields protected in the base class if the child class wants to immediately access the parent's fields.

It could also be a missing clean-up after copying the class source. So check the field's usage, and maybe other child classes.

```
public abstract class Car {

    protected final Product product;
    protected final String carType;

    public Car(Product product,String carType){
        this.product = product;
        this.carType = carType;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your SuperClass and subclass have same private variables name. So when you call super from subclass, the members belonging to superclass are initialised which are not visible to subclass. Hence, subclass members need to be initialized again.
But, i do not understand why would somebody have superclass & subclass with the same final members and how would they fit in bigger picture.

Answer (score 0):

It is redundant to initialize the properties with the same name in the `child` class. As you noticed it is enough to do it in `super` class.